# simple code, help, noob here. In assignment i cant just copy the function. How can I get around that?

Tags: python, recipe

This is a recipe that changes depending on how many people they are.

Then the assignment says that the code should then print out the recipe for 4 people and then 7 with a script *"important that it is not just a new function"*.

[This is how the file looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHVH8.png)

```
import math


print("Detta är ett recept på sockerkaka som ändras beroende på hur många serveringar 
som ska göras. ")
m = int(input("Skriv antal serveringar:"))
print(m * 0.5, "tsk vaniljsocker")
print(m * 0.75, "dl strösocker")
print(m * 0.5, "tsk bakpulver")
print(m * 18.75, "g smör")
print(m * 0.25, "dl vatten")
print(math.floor(m * 0.75), "st ägg")
print(m * 0.75, "dl vetemjöl")
print(10 + m, "minuter för att blanda smeten")
print(30 + 3*m, "minuter för att grädda kakorna")
print("Total tid för tillagning:",10 + m + 30 + 3*m, "min")
```

Comment: "But it should use the earlier function"

Comment: ung svensk, I don't understand why you don't call a function... you want to use a lambda function?

Comment: It sure sounds like you're supposed to write one function and then call it twice

Comment: @KjellbergWille, somebody upvoted the answer, so probably it should work for you, check it.

Comment: @KjellbergWille, you can accept one answer if it worked, otherwise feel free to ask in the comments

Comment: @KjellbergWille, did it work for you?

Answer (score 4):

## A function

---

You can use a function, like this:

```
def recipe(people: int) -> str:
    m = people
    recipe_ = f"""{m * 0.5} tsk vaniljsocker\n
    {m * 0.75} dl strosocker\n""" # Complete the recipe like this
    return recipe_
```

---

Than you can call the function like this:

```
>>> recipe(people)
```

If you want to know more about functions in python, look at this:

- [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp)

---

If you really want to make the number of people to be an input, you can do like this:

```
people = int(input("your text"))
recipe(people)
```

## Repeating the function

---

If you want to have the recipe more than one time, you can call the function twice or trice.

```
x = int(input("How many recipes do you want to have?"))
for _ in range(x):
    people = int(input("your text"))
    print(recipe(people))
```

If you want to know more about for loops in python, look at this:

- [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp)

## F-strings

---

In Python3 there are several ways to format a string, for example the `.format()` string method.

```
>>> years = int(input("How old are you"))
>>> "I'm {} years old".format(years)
```

Another way to do this is the f-string method:

```
>>> f"I'm {years} years old"
```

If you want a longer explaination, look at this:

- [realpython](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)
- [docs.python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

## round() or floor()

---

Then, you can round the `st ägg` amount without importing math module, using the `built-in` method `round()`:

```
>>> round(10.3)
10
>>> round(10.3, 1)
10.3
```

You can read more about round there:

- [riptutorial](https://riptutorial.com/python/example/854/rounding--round--floor--ceil--trunc)

Comment: @André, you're right, the functions according to PEP-8 should be snake_case. Now I'm going to edit to explain about f-strings. Thank you for your suggestions